# Turning off the Spring MVC data binder

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

first post on stackoverflow... I'm starting to play around with SpringMVC and I was trying to figure out what would be the best approach to link my entities to the web views as stateless as possible.

One way I've found is to use the @ModelAttribute on a method that receive in parameter (from the request) the entity ID, which finds it from the service/persistence layer, and return it so it is inserted into the Model of the current request.

In addition, Spring MVC binds any incoming parameter that matches a field of my entity and updates its value automatically (through the WebDataBinder).

My question is concerning this last behaviour. I find it useful that my entity gets updated when some data has been posted by the client. But I would like to avoid it on a simple GET request (which I see as read-only). Current behaviour would allow to update the entity by adding parameter in the query of such request, which could be a security issue.

I know about the dataBinder.setAllowedFields() and stuff but I would prefer a way to disable any kind of field mapping a any GET request. Is there any way to do it?

Thanks!

Edited: I have added a sample prototype to make it clearer what I am looking for...

```
@ModelAttribute Entity retrieveEntity(@RequestParam(required=true) Long id) {
    // This is called before the request handler and before parameters are mapped to the entity
    return entityRepository.get(id);
}

@RequestMapping(value="/modify", method=RequestMethod.POST) 
public ModelAndView handleModifyRequest(@ModelAttribute Entity entity) {
    // Here, I want my entity to reflect the parameters passed in the posted form (this works)
    ....
}

@RequestMapping(value="/read", method=RequestMethod.GET) 
public ModelAndView handleReadRequest(@ModelAttribute Entity entity) {
    // Here, I DON'T want my entity to reflect the parameters passed in the URL (which is what happens...)
    ....
}
```

Comment: Why would you map a GET request to a method that updates your model?

Comment: That's the point : I don't want it to be able to update my model. I want to use the @ModelAttribute method to retrieve the entity to "get". But for security purposes, I want to disable the data binding that will automatically update my entity (the target) if any parameter matching one of its field is passed in the URL.

Comment: Ok, but why not simply map POST requests to entity changing methods and do no entity update in the method mapped to GET requests? IF you only retrieve entities and put them in your view in a method, there will be no update, will there?

Comment: If I retrieve my entity using a @ModelAttribute annoted method, like I would like, the update is automatically applied by the SpringMVC layer, which I don't want.

Comment: My idea would be to create a new annotation `@ReadOnlyModelAttribute` and an aspect with @Around advice for the controller methods and fill `@ReadOnlyModelAttribute` objects in the aspect. But – is it worth the time?

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I decided to go with something like this, since it seems that the parameter mapping happen only if the request handler method takes a ModelAttribute parameter

```
@ModelAttribute Entity retrieveEntity(@RequestParam(required=true) Long id) {
    return entityRepository.get(id);
}

@RequestMapping(value="/modify", method=RequestMethod.POST) 
public ModelAndView handleModifyRequest(@ModelAttribute Entity entity) {
    // Here, the request parameters have been mapped to the entity
    ....
}

@RequestMapping(value="/read", method=RequestMethod.GET) 
public ModelAndView handleReadRequest(ModelMap model) {
    // This will avoid any parameter mapping to the entity
    Entity entity = (Entity)model.get("entity");
    ....
}
```

Any better solution is welcome! Thanks